# WP_Query outputs wrong post in custom post type

Tags: posts, wp-query, wp-admin

So I'm working directly in the **Admin Dashboard** of my website, below I will explain what I'm attempting to achieve and what issues I'm getting.

**Here is the code**:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'set_scheduled_today_tag', 99);
function set_scheduled_today_tag() {
    $query = new WP_Query([
        'post_type' => 'wp_events',
        'post_status' => ['schedule'],
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    ]);
    if ($query->have_posts()):
        while ($query->have_posts()):
            $query->the_post();
            $post_date = get_the_date('Y/m/d', get_the_ID());
            $current_date = date('Y/m/d');
            if ($post_date === $current_date) {
                wp_set_post_terms(get_the_ID(), 'Today', 'event_tag', true);
            }
        endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();

    echo '<style>
            .event_tag-checked {
                background-color: lightblue!important;
            }
            .event_tag-today {
                background-color: #90EE90!important;
            }
          </style>';
}
```

**Here is what I've completed**:

- When the post "Date" matches the current date, append a "Today" tag to the post tag and change the color.

[image]

**Here is the issue**:

*Before this implementation, I had no problems*, but now when I click into a specific post, I get a different post that displays.

- If I hover over the Koe Wetzel post, it comes back with Post ID: 6608 - This post doesn't even exist in the DB.
- When I open the post, it leads me to a random event under my `wp_events` post_type such as Weird Al  Yankovic: Unfortunate Return of the Ill-Advised Vanity Tour.

**Questions**:

- Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong with my query?
- Am I properly querying posts on the admin post_type side of things?
- Can I query the posts differently?

All help will be appreciated!

Comment: If you really want people to read your code, remove everything redundant like `<style>` from the code and leave only the essential code. When removed, please, come back.

Comment: Read the rules. One question.

Comment: This question is 100% correct, will leave as is.

Comment: Three questions in one are out of rules!

Comment: I don't know where you're getting three questions from, this is all one question particular to WP_Query just reworded differently. Thanks for downvoting since you don't know how to read.

Comment: Questions:

    * Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong with my query?
    * Am I properly querying posts on the admin post_type side of things?
   * Can I query the posts differently? **Three at all.**

Comment: @MaxYudin It's okay. The one, basic question here is how to approach this problem, and the "three" questions document the thought process. Also for short code like this, I think keeping it complete is fine, because now we can rule out syntax and logic errors.

Comment: @fuxia this has just been solved.

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved.

```
add_action('admin_head', 'set_scheduled_today_tag', 99);
function set_scheduled_today_tag() {
    global $post;
    $args = [
        'post_type' => 'wp_events',
        'post_status' => 'any',
        'numberposts' => -1
    ];
    $posts = get_posts($args);
    if ($posts) {
        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            setup_postdata($post);
            $post_date = get_the_date('Y/m/d', get_the_ID());
            date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
            $current_date = date('Y/m/d');
            if ($post_date === $current_date) {
                wp_set_object_terms(get_the_ID(), 'today', 'event_tag', true);
            }
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    echo '<style>
            .event_tag-checked {
                background-color: lightblue!important;
            }
            .event_tag-today {
                background-color: #90EE90!important;
            }
          </style>';
}
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** did that solve the problem?